# how to get first person in xslt?

Tags: xml, xslt

I have code like dis

```
    <xsl:if test='last-name="andrew"'>
print first person
</xsl:if>
```

So how to get the first `person` with last name andrew ?

Comment: Not like that, there is no xpath of 'last-name' as 'last-name' is not part of the XSLT or XPATH function standard. What is your XML - post it here. Without that we can only guess.

Comment: It would be helpful to provide a short XML document so that people will not have to guess.

Comment: @Woody your comment seems mis-placed. In the posted code last-name is selecting an element of that name, so the fact that there is no function of that name is not relevant.

Comment: @David - without the XML that he is using, any answer is a guess, and I was indicating that that needed to be the name of either a function or a node.

Comment: @Woody that's a very generous reading of your initial comment. The posted code is valid xpath and would not refer to a function even if a function of that name existed in the library. So the statement "there is no xpath of 'last-name' " was wrong and the statement "not part of the XSLT or XPATH function standard" is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

> how to get the first person with last name andrew

**If the context (current) node is the parent of the `person` elements, the XPath expression you want is**:

```
person[last-name = 'andrew'][1]
```

This selects the first (in document order) child of the context node, such that its name is `person` and the string value of its first `last-name` child is the string `"andrew"`.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your source hard to be definite but probably

```
select='person[last-name="andrew"][1]'
```

assuming a structure such as

```
<person><first-name>David</first-name><last-name>Carlisle</last-name></person>
<person><first-name>David</first-name><last-name>andrew</last-name></person>
<person><first-name>andrew</first-name><last-name>andrew</last-name></person>
```

Comment: David, the OP wants to select the *first* `person` with the desired properties.

Comment: yes I think I'd edited it by the time you commented:-) I wrote last() rather than 1 in the first version, mis-read the question.